# jquery .find() not working as expected on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad

I have this HTML:

```
<div id = "note">
    <div id = "selection"></div>
    <div id = "element"></div>
</div>

<div id = "note">
    <div id = "selection"></div>
    <div id = "element"></div>
</div>

<div id = "note">
    <div id = "selection"></div>
    <div id = "element"></div>
</div>
```

and jquery code:

```
$("[id=note]").each(function(){

    $(this).find("#selection").css("left", left).css("top", top);

});
```

when using desktop everything works as expected.
when using ipad (safari or chrome) - at the end of the .each function I get all elements with id = "#selection" having the same left and top.

I used wen inspector to debug the code, and in console when I run $(this).find("#selection") I get all the three elements having id = "#selection"

Do I miss something?
Is there a known issue using ".find()" on ipad?

Comment: typo `$("[id=note")`, and Duplicate Ids

Comment: You're missing a `]` in the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Id should be unique. Use class instead of it,

```
<div class = "note">
    <div class = "selection"></div>
    <div class = "element"></div>
</div>

<div class = "note">
    <div class = "selection"></div>
    <div class = "element"></div>
</div>

<div class = "note">
    <div class = "selection"></div>
    <div class = "element"></div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(".note").each(function(){

    $(this).find(".selection").css("left", left).css("top", top);

});
```

**Edit**
Like @Barmar suggested, you dont have to loop through each element for applying a common style, You can directly use like this

```
$(".note .selection").css({left: left, top: top})
```

Comment: No need for `.find`. Just `$(".note .selection").css({left: left, top: top})`.

Comment: @Barmar you are correct. Then there is no need for loop also.

Answer (score 0):

Ids should be unique. for similar ids, id selector only finds the first elements ion matched DOM. use class instead:

**HTML:**

```
<div class= "note">
  <div class= "selection"></div>
  <div class= "element"></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
  $(".note .selection").css({"left":left,"top":top});
```

Comment: If you're going to simplify it, go all the way `$(".note .selection").css(...)`.

Comment: @Barmar: thanks man...did not looked the each part carefully n confused it with event.

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of Id. Beacuse id is unique in html

```
$("[class=note]").each(function(){

    $(this).find(".selection").css({"left":left , top : top});

});
```

Comment: You're also missing a `]`.